# Anylogic windows to write code are too small

Tags: ubuntu, anylogic, ubuntu-22.04

I've installed Anylogic latest version in Ubuntu 22.04 but I have problem with the software interface
windows to write code in properties view into are like 3 pixels high (can't see what I'm typing)
you can see in the screen
[screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GR33i.png)
[screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOes0.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer I got from AnyLogic support. Have only tested it on Ubutunu 22.04 LTS.

1. Create a `gtk.css` file in this folder: `~/.config/gtk-3.0/` If the file already exists, that fine.
2. Add the following content:

```
scrollbar slider {
  min-height: 10px;
}
```

You can adjust the `min-height` value to something that works for you.   I set mine to `12`.